# PHP contact avoid Spam

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

In this question I will take 2 parts of my problem.

**PART 1:**

I have a php + javascript validator form that sends an e-mail to my client if right rand numbers (generated by php) are validated by javascript.
So far so good...
The problem is that rand numbers are not sufficient to avoid SPAM (in fact, my client receives approx 20 per day e-mails by fake Adidas campaign). So, my idea comes from getting a rand number + 10 (forcing user to solve the calculation).

**PART 2:**

I am not preety sure what is the best way to solve this, but I think in this 3 options:

1. Sum rand number inside php variable;
2. Read rand number in javascript and sum 10 inside javascript;
3. Read rand number generated by `php` and sum another rand number.

---

### **Here is my code, without sum:**

***PHP***

```
$ran_num = rand(0,9999);
$exclude_check = "valid";
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
if (document.getElementById("spambox").value != "<?php echo $ran_num ?>") {
alert('<?php echo $spamerror_s5_qc ?>');
return false;
}
```

Comment: How you are sending mail? are you usnig SMTP or mail() function of php?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi — Why would that matter?

Comment: i dont think spamming of your mail is related to your validation, otherwise i understood wrong your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent spam bots from filling out web form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185795/prevent-spam-bots-from-filling-out-web-form)

Comment: Spambots don't use JavaScript. You have to do the validation on the server side.

Comment: i tried doing random number + random number converted to word (ie: `3 + ____ = seven`) and it still got spam. in the end, the best thing i've found is a "honeypot". Essentially hide a field from users with javascript that if it is filled out, don't process the form.

Comment: @robz228 Honeypot is the best way for me to do this. I totally unknown this way. Thanks a lot man. Can you please anwser that to close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple honeypot example which is the most effective method i've seen that doesn't involve ip banning and stuff.

You'll want to put on your form a field you intend for users to NOT fill out. Then hide it with javascript on the frontend. Bots won't have javascript so they will see this field and fill it out.  Make it named something that sounds important like 'required' or 'first_name' etc.

then on your PHP:

```
if($_POST['first_name']){
    //YA FILTHY BOT!
}
else{
     //process form
}
```